# to_pandas() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python-3.x, pyarrow

I am trying to convert a parquet table to pandas data frame, and to avoid memory doubling as per the documentation([enter link description here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/pandas.html)), I used following code;

```
df = table.to_pandas(split_blocks=True, self_destruct=True)
```

But I am getting following error;

```
TypeError: to_pandas() got an unexpected keyword argument 'split_blocks'
```

Right now I have the pyarrow version 0.15.1 installed. When I run the code `Conda update pyarrow` I get the message, `required packages are installed`.

May I know how can this error be remedied. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 0.15.1 support fewer options than the latest version. You can see the options [here](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/apache-arrow-0.15.1/python/pyarrow/array.pxi#L472). If you are worried about memory you can try to pass `zero_copy=True`.

I'm not an expert in conda, but have you tried `conda install pyarrow=1.0.1`